# Issue with checking whether an IP address exists in database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am currently making a simple IP address banning script and I am at the stage where the admin will enter a new IP address to be inserted into the database. The issue I am having is that my check to see if the IP address already exists always returns `IP address is already banned` even when I enter an IP address that isn't already in the database.

My database consists of a table called `banned_ips` and three columns; `id, ip and reason`.

Here is my query:

```
if ($_POST) {
    if ($_POST['ip'] != '' && $_POST['reason'] != '') {
        if (strlen($_POST['ip']) <= 15 && strlen($_POST['reason']) <= 255) {
            $ip = $_POST['ip'];
            $reason = $_POST['reason'];

            $ip_clean = htmlentities($ip);
            $reason_clean = htmlentities($reason);

            if (isset($ip_clean, $reason_clean)) {
                $check_ip = $db->prepare("SELECT `ip` FROM `banned_ips` WHERE `ip` = ? LIMIT 1");
                $check_ip->bind_param('s', $ip_clean);
                $res = $check_ip->execute();
                if ($res) {
                    $_SESSION['ip_exists'] = 'Exists';
                } else {
                $insert_ip = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `banned_ips` (ip, reason) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $insert_ip->bind_param('ss', $ip_clean, $reason_clean);

                if ($insert_ip->execute()) {
                    // Successful insert
                    $_SESSION['successful_insert'] = 'Success';
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My issue in other words, is even when I try to ban an IP that doesn't already exist in the table, it thinks it does. I have set the `ip` column to unique, to prevent duplication however I am doing this to display an error message.

Comment: I don't know the reason for putting `htmlentities` in there, but it's the wrong solution no matter what the reason.

Answer (score 3):

The `execute()` function returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure. 0 rows isn't a failure. Use `num_rows` to get the number of rows returned.